# Send an intent to only one service

Tags: android, service, android-intent, intentfilter

Is it possible to send an intent only to one service when this one is running?
I'm aware of the functions `startService()` and `onStartCommand()` but I don't want "start" the service, in my case it was already started.

So I would like to know if it is possible to target only one brodcast receiver or if it exits something else to send only to one service/activity?

My tries with `intent.setClass()` before the `sendBroadcast(intent)` were not concluents.

Comment: `startService()` will not necessarily start the service again if it is already running. Are you trying to send an message to a specific `Service` object? If so, why? Services should be able to shut down and start again fluidly. Could do with more specific information, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm aware of the functions startService() and onStartCommand() but I don't want "start" the service, in my case it was already started.

`startService()` merely delivers a message to an existing running copy of the service, via `onStartCommand()`, if there is such a copy. It will create such a copy (thereby triggering a call to `onCreate()`) if there is no running copy of the service.

> So I would like to know if it is possible to target only one brodcast receiver or if it exits something else to send only to one service/activity?

Use `startService()`, please.

Comment: I know that `startService()` can be invoke more than once but I doubted that was a good practice. Apparently it is, so I will use it.